# I get error when use AFNetworking in xcode for download file

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, afnetworking

I create one application that has one page and in this page exist one button that downloaded file when click on.

I can download file with AFNetworking but in my has error ....

this is my code :

```
- (IBAction)downloads:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"start downloads");
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
   [NSURL URLWithString:
   @"http://.../500x333xgalaxy-core-product-image-1tn.jpg,
                           q1367836642.pagespeed.ic.eafBYU8jUN.jpg"]];
    AFURLConnectionOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                                             initWithRequest:request];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                                   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent
                                                                        :@"filename.jpg"];

    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, 
    id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}
```

[image]

this error is :

```
No visible @interface 'AFURLConnectionOpretion' declares the selector
                                                         'setCompletionBlockWithSuccess'
```

Comment: "AFURLConnectionOperation *operation" change this to "AFHTTPRequestOperation   *operation"

Comment: my friend right it but I dont download file from url!!! why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following line to start the operation :

```
[operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my download code

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *urlConnection;
urlConnection = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
urlConnection.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:outputPath append:NO];
[urlConnection setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Download Completed");


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error occured while downloading");

}];

[urlConnection setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

}];
```

change "AFURLConnectionOperation *operation" to "AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation"
i think thats the issue

Comment: u mean still not downloading ?

Comment: check your url, copy paste that in browser and check if it's working